# Unable to update Thumbnail link of a file in google drive v3 api

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I was doing an experiment with google drive-v3 API from the curl tool. Here I have created the new empty file (with filename alone) with below API.

```
curl --request POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS-TOKEN]' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{'\''name'\'':'\''New-EmptyFile.jpg'\'','\''parents'\'':['\''1_m7AipvwhKayhy6awYETqJYnp51vU_I1'\''],'\''mimeType'\'':'\''image/jpeg'\''}' --compressed
```

The new empty image file gets created without image data and thumbnail.

```
{
    "id": "170zfkmx03z0NzGOwp0f0loGj1Q4rAJt7",
    "name": "New-EmptyFile.jpg",
    "createdTime": "2019-04-05T20:19:02.077Z"
}
```

So, I have tried to update the thumbnail for the image file using the thumbnail link of one of a file that already exists in my google drive but I was getting the below error.

Thumbnail link:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8Xb7kzH-cggIF-NfH5qjiHc_nea0ZhlYW_tcsfX6-W37UZIhiBIljvyRs4c7MGC_-h4K5fB-hZg=s220
```

Curl command to update thumbnail:

```
curl -# --request PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/170zfkmx03z0NzGOwp0f0loGj1Q4rAJt7 --header 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlvjBgWHr1i1uM_yJCBkw7du50QbCWbJ0jb0kVZEfRudisakYW2hs681cYbhdxrTpFuhLPdjzPilyccoG_TiKTG_YmeLOv4mu2BAuNf3ZCxXpOmexLSjdm657VZK' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"thumbnailLink":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8Xb7kzH-cggIF-NfH5qjiHc_nea0ZhlYW_tcsfX6-W37UZIhiBIljvyRs4c7MGC_-h4K5fB-hZg=s220"}' --compressed
```

Error Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "fieldNotWritable",
    "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
 }
}
```

How to resolve and update the thumbnail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/file#uploading_thumbnails) says as follows.

> If Drive can generate a thumbnail from the file, then it will use the generated one and ignore any you may have uploaded. If it can't generate a thumbnail, it will always use yours if you provided one.

By this, unfortunately, the thumbnail of image file cannot be modified.

- Although I tried to modify the thumbnail of image file, I confirmed that in the current stage, that cannot be achieved, yet.
- For example, in the case of the zip file, the thumbnail can be modified.

#### Reference:

- [Uploading thumbnails](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/file#uploading_thumbnails)

Comment: @KIRUBAKARAN S Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved.